# Web URL in SSRS dataset results

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2012

I have a SSRS 2012 report that I have built using the SQL Server data tools, inside one of the datasets fields is text and URL's. The URL's should be a hyperlink when the report is viewed via a web browser, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by following these steps:

1. **Right click** on the field you would like to be a hyperlink
2. Select **Text Box Properties**
3. Select the **Action** tab
4. Change the action option to **Go to URL**
5. Select the **URL field** from the dropdown

You need to ensure that the URL is in your dataset. If you would like the field label to be different from the URL then simply assign the field to the description field from your dataset as you would normally.

You will notice that there is no visual indicator to the user that this field/Cell is now a hyperlink and that it is clickable. what i generally like to do is to color the font in blue and underline the hyperlink text.